# Java ThreadPoolExecutor not creating new threads?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I want to remove values from a shared list of Integers using different threads. To do this, I decided to use ThreadPoolExecutor service.

First, I created a BlockingQueue to store 1 million values.

```
 BlockingQueue q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        q.add(i);
```

Second, my ThreadPoolExecutor

```
 ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
 MyExecutorJob job = new MyExecutorJob(q);
 executor.execute(job);
```

The body of the job class is this:

```
public class MyExecutorJob extends Thread
{
   private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

   public MyExecutorJob(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue)
   {
    this.queue = queue;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
       try
       {
           while (!queue.isEmpty())
           {
               Integer x = (Integer) queue.take();
               System.out.println(x + " - " + this.getName());
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
       }

   }
}
```

The result is always

```
1 - Thread-0 
2 - Thread-0 
3 - Thread-0 
4 - Thread-0 
....
100000 - Thread-0
```

It looks like my job is not being executed by two threads. It's always the same thread.
I need to loop through the list of integer values using two threads.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I dont see?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you actually `submit` more than one job instance?

Comment: You are only submitting one job to the ``ThreadPoolExecutor``. That job is passed to exactly one thread. Try to call ``executor.execute(job);`` a second time.

Comment: Also note that `this.getName()` is completely unrelated to the name of the thread that is executing this code. For that use `Thread.currentThread().getName()`. It will be something like `pool-0-thread-0`. You should not have your job class extend Thread. Implement Runnable or Callable instead. Otherwise you are only confusing yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought I needed to call executor.execute(job) only once. It's working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.the error is `this.getName()`, please use `Thread.currentThread().getName()`;

2.you have initialized a thread pool which has two thread, but you has only one job, then the thread pool will only offer a thread to execute your job;

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way but for testing replace `100000` with `100`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    IntStream.range(0, 100000).forEach(i ->
        executor.execute(() -> System.out.println(i + " - " + currentThread().getName())));
}
```